# How to give in app update to add/remove features in my app without any update from Playstore?

Tags: android, android-studio, backend, firebase-remote-config, in-app-update

I'm designing an Android app in which I need a feature that can enable me to do

1. Update app of users for new features even though they are not updated from Playstore.
2. With out app update in Playstore I can add/remove new features.

Ex: I had seen apps like Telegram and Google chrome in my old phone. I hadn't updated those apps from almost 2years but many new features are added to them (may be core features not added). I also checked the versions of those apps, still they are on older versions.

How can I add this type in app update feature in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 Ways:

1. Use firebase remote config to set flags for each module and based on the the flag setting, enable/disable functionality within your app without new update to Appstore. You can also hide/show Icons for these features based on remote config flag.
2. On App launch call config file from your server, and check what functionality to show to user. Backend portal should configure the modules to be shown in app.

Comment: It's ok to enable/disable existing functionality present in app. But my doubt is can we give extra functionality and features that are not exit in app?